# Can gravity and hydro power be utilized in a closed system to generate efficient electricity?

Tags: energy, gravity, power

[image]This is my second post on this topic. The first one had some flaws but I resolved them with this new design. This is more of a thought experiment - which I don't think is that outlandish given Einstein had many such thought experiments. The key idea is catching a falling ball via a hook attached to the BOTTOM of the ball. Once setup within a pendulum contraption the ball is dropped and will rotate and thus bring the water back up to the top of the sphere. The pendulum is reset after each swing via computer - it does not swing back and forth. This is not perpetual motion. A computer will control catching and dropping the ball and resetting the pendulum to the most optimum state between swings. Losses in height will occur. The key question is can this be constructed in such a way as to achieve limitless, efficient, clean hydropower just utilizing gravity in a clever way?

Hydropower is the most efficient way to generate electricity. Modern hydro turbines can convert as much as 90% of the available energy into electricity. The best fossil fuel plants are only about 50% efficient. I imagine if this could be constructed below a small lake not suited for a normal hydro power plant then the water could simply fill the sphere at the top of the building (no need for pumping up to top) and then the water is released once the ball reaches the bottom of the building. The ball is then hoisted back up (empty), filled from lake water that is level with the top of the building, and the swinging back and forth is repeated as efficiently as possible. How many swings you get is determined by how big and tall you make the power plant and how optimized the cables are in between swings. The ball should also be constructed to be as light as possible because it will need to be hoisted back up to the top of the building.

Comment: What's the point of the swinging? Bringing the water to the top of the sphere while lowering the sphere accomplishes nothing - you could have just lowered the sphere and accomplished the same thing. Also, "limitless energy" implies perpetual motion - you're basically saying you can extract energy from the system, but never have it run out, meaning the system will be in motion... perpetually.

Comment: Personal theories are off-topic here.  Also you are trying to refine an engineering design - we do not do engineering here and it is a specific reason to close questions.  Finally your are trying to make a perpetual motion machine and this is not mainstream physics and the site explicitly deals only with mainstream physics.  So your question could be considered off-topic for a number of reasons.

Comment: "Bringing the water to the top of the sphere while lowering the sphere accomplishes nothing" Once it's back at the top it can fall through the turbine again - over and over. Thought this was obvious. It's the whole point of the design - the water falls through a turbine after it's brought back up to the top.

Answer (score 4):

As long as your entire apparatus is sitting in a gravitational field, there is no way to devise a "clever cheat" that turns gravitational potential energy into limitless mechanical work. This is not because we humans are simply not clever enough to think up some way to do this, it's because of the way that gravity works: the relationship between one's height above ground and one's gravitational potential energy does not depend on the path you took in achieving that height.

You can prove mathematically that the only way to beat gravity at this game (in other words, to violate energy conservation) and get infinite free energy is if you could invent a way to temporarily turn gravity off, rearrange your masses, and then turn gravity back on.

The universe we happen to inhabit is not structured in a way that makes it possible for us to turn gravity on and off, no matter how badly we might want to. Energy is conserved, and  there is no free lunch.

Answer (score 1):

If your lake is as high as a building then it will be more efficient to have a hydro electric generator at the bottom of the building. Also if your ball empties the water at the bottom and refills at the top, it is not a closed system. In ANY case you cannot get more energy from falling water than it takes to lift it. While there is no way of creating energy from nothing, there are usually more efficient ways of harnessing available energy, so always keep thinking and learning. Good luck.